# C argv[] to double and operate with it

Tags: c, double, operations

Is there a way to get a double with the ARGV[] function?

I've tried this, but it did not work in the way i want it to. My "solution" code is:

```
int MarkGenerator(double argc, double argv[])
{
    if (argc > 3){
        OnError("Too few arguments for mark calculator", -3);
    }
    else{
        double MaxPoint = argv[1];
        double PointsReached = argv[2];
        double temp = 0;


        temp = PointsReached * MaxPoint;
        printf("%d\n", temp);
        temp = temp * 5;
        printf("%d\n", temp);
        temp = temp ++;
        printf("%d\n", temp);
    }
}
```

The code works, but not in the way i want it to.

any solutions?

Comment: Actually it *won't* work, as the arguments to `main` are passed as an integer and an array of character pointers. Trying to make it something else like you do will only lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: `argv[]` is not a function .

Comment: I also feel compelled to point out you're checking for too MANY arguments, not too few.

Comment: ..and you do not know how to use prinf().

Comment: I'm sorry for writing some mistakes in the code. It was 5 o'clock in the morning.

Comment: And telling me what i don't know helps nobody. I'm in this forum to get answers and help. And learn out of my mistakes. Nobody was born as an programmer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some suggested changes.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
```

//argc is an int and argv is an array of char *

```
int MarkGenerator(int argc, char * argv[])  
{

    if (argc < 3){

        OnError("Too few arguments for mark calculator", -3);

    }else{
// The function gets its arguments as strings (char *).
// Take each of the strings and convert it to double
        double MaxPoint = strtod(argv[1], NULL);

        double PointsReached = strtod(argv[2], NULL);

        double temp = 0;   


        temp = PointsReached * MaxPoint;
// Use "%lf" to print a double
        printf("%lf\n", temp);

        temp = temp * 5;

        printf("%lf\n", temp);

        temp = temp ++;

        printf("%lf\n", temp);

    }

}
```

//argc is an int and argv is an array of char *

// main function's standard signature

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])

{

 // Note how arguments are passed
 MarkGenerator(argc, argv);

}
```

Comment: Thanks, after fixing some issues and with the help of your code, it finally worked.